# Using .match() in ReactJS - match is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, filter, match

I'm trying to use `match()` to filter results from an array in **React** :

```
if (this.props.search) {
   tracks.filter(result => {
      return result.match(`/${this.props.search}/gi`);
   });
}
```

But I'm getting :

```
TypeError: result.match is not a function
```

Am I missing something really obvious here? It's been a long day :/

Example of ***tracks*** array :

```
0:
  active: 1
  artist: "CJ Bolland"
  date_added: "2019-01-03 05:08:10"
  date_modified: "2019-01-03 05:09:01"
  duration: "00:05:54"
  filename: "1546488490.mp3"
  id: 2
  in_playlist: false
  online: 1
  seconds: 354
  time_ago: "1 hour ago"
  title: "Sugar Is Sweeter (AVH Mix)"
  type: "track"
  user_id: 4

1:
  active: 1
  artist: "Cristoph"
  date_added: "2019-01-03 05:08:46"
  date_modified: "2019-01-03 05:10:01"
  duration: "00:06:34"
  filename: "1546488526.mp3"
  id: 3
  in_playlist: false
  online: 1
  seconds: 394
  time_ago: "1 hour ago"
  title: "Guffaz"
  type: "track"
  user_id: 3
```

**** EDIT ****
Here is a screen shot of what's happening after implementing [Just code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630817/just-code)'s solution (which is working fine here on SO, but not in React). As you can see, I'm logging 3 things, the original array, the search term and the filtered array, but the filtered array always returns empty.

[image]

Comment: what is tracks and what data is there in it?

Comment: It's an associative array

Comment: can you share the sample data of `tracks`?

Comment: Just added it ;)

Comment: you are using `match` function to an object in your filter function

Comment: it should be like result.artist.match(`/${this.props.search}/gi`)

Comment: So there is no way of doing a global search of all items in each array object?

Comment: `global search` which means if any of the property in that object contains that search value, you want that object, right?

Comment: Yeah, so anything searched for can be found in any field, although in reality only the artist and title will probably be the only useful ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your regex is transformed to the string and the regex is not working properly,
You can do something like this, when it comes to string interpolation regexp object is always a handy.

```
return result.match(new RegExp(`${search}`,'gi'));
```

```js
var tracks = [{
  artist: "CJ Bolland",
  title: "Sugar Is Sweeter (AVH Mix)"
}, {
  artist: "Cristoph",
  title: "Guffaz"
}];
var search = "sug";
var filtered = tracks.filter(result => {
  return result.artist.match(new RegExp(`${search}`, 'gi')) || result.title.match(new RegExp(`${search}`, 'gi'));
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Can I apply this match to both the artist and title fields at the same time?

Comment: @spice yes check my edit you can use && or || as per your requirements

Comment: Thanks bro. It's still not working though. I'm getting back an empty array for anything I search for. Could it be due to both the tracks array and the search string being props passed down from a parent? I didn't think .filter mutated though?

Comment: @spice what is your expectation the search should match both or any?

Comment: Should match either field (artist or title) and should be a fuzzy match. ie - `sug` would return the first object - so case should be irrelevant too (which I thought I was already doing with `i`). Also important that it is able to return multiple objects that match.

Comment: @spice check my snippet now, it has real example

Comment: Thanks man. Yep it works fine on here. Just don't know why it's returning an empty array in React. I'm console logging the search prop and I can see that it's being populated correctly. I'm a bit stumped with this one.

Comment: @spice create stackblitz link if you an

Comment: It's too big of an app bro. Despite the many components that make it run, it's loading the data via a locked down php based api. Would be a ton of work of to throw a stackblitz together. I'll add a screen shot of my console so you can see what's happening.

Comment: @spice that won't help in that case you will have to check the flow of the props, you can debug it and check where it is going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I know that doesn't really help. Oh well thanks for your help anyway. I'll figure it out. Now I know I was using match incorrectly that's got me a step closer anyway, so thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: Doh! Found it.... I was using the `AND` operator instead of `OR`. That's why I wasn't getting any results. It's working now, and if ever there was a sign that I needed some sleep.... haha. Thanks again bro ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was trying tô use match in a number. So i just used `.toString()` before using `.match()`.